# Hotkey for SpaceUVEditor.show_texpaint

Tags: python, interface, customization

I would like to use `wm.context_toggle` to work with `SpaceUVEditor.show_texpaint`. What would be the proper Context Attribute (if it is actually possible to do this)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the two criteria is the active object in the 3dview has to have a mode of PAINT_TEXTURE and it has to have a uvmap.

Comment: Those conditions are met, but it doesn't work.